# How to change active tab after button click

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton, tabview

I used PrimeFaces component [tabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml) and i have code like below.

```
 <p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:tab id="tab1">
         <ui:include src="/some/path/page.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2">
         <ui:include src="/some/path/page2.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab3">
         <ui:include src="/some/path/page3.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

On page3 i have ajax [commandButton](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml) which looks like below.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.method(parameter)}" ajax="true" value="Add" />
```

I need switch to tab1 when method in bean finished. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add:

```
activeIndex
```

attribute to your tabView:

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true" cache="false" activeIndex="1" >
```

Comment: you need to update tab after call command button on third tab. and it will show you first tab.